# How to read Chrome console error message using Javascript or Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to get obvious message when Javascript has error and don't need to open ChromeDevTools.
Anyway is ok,JS or Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `JavaScript Errors Notifier` Chrome Extension to get that error message.

Comment: Have you been setting it up?

Comment: i chose all options

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate the `Console` class...

```js
function logger(type, $delegate, ...args) {
  $delegate("Called", type, args);
}

for(let prop in console) {
  if(console.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    let $original = console[prop];
    if(!($original instanceof Function)) {
      continue;
    }
    
    console[prop] = function(...args) {
      logger(prop, $original, ...args);
      return $original.call(console, ...args);
    }
  }
}

console.log("Greetings");
```